# How to boot Wince 6 using uboot?

Tags: windows-ce, boot, u-boot

On my simulation platform, I can use uboot to boot a linux kernel, and use eboot to boot wince6 kernel. But Can I boot Wince 6 using uboot directly? Or I need to let uboot chainload eboot? What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

uboot can certainly load CE just like it can Linux.  How is a complex question, though.  It depends on how you boot from eboot.  Do you XIP?  Do you copy the OS to RAM and jump to it?

All you need to do is modify uboot to do the same steps eboot is doing (e.g. enable MMU, enable caching, copy from media to RAM, jump to address) and it will work.  Your Linux kernel likely requires the exact same set of steps, so it's probably not a lot of changes.

Comment: I am using ARM RVDS debugger. I did copy the uboot image and wince image to RAM. I can successfully run uboot, and interrupt to uboot process. Then I run "go 0x"WINCE_START_ADDRESS"" and it doesn't run the wince kernel.

Comment: Is the OS uncompressed at that location?  Is it in RAM?

Comment: As ctacke said, if you are loading from RAM you should use a decompressed image. You can do that by using an image with extension .nb0 instead of the usual nk.bin. This article (http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/05/17/platform-builder--creating-an-nk.nb0.aspx) is a good reference about the difference between the two.

Comment: @yms's comment - dead link, archived contents at http://web.archive.org/web/20090610044831/http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/05/17/platform-builder--creating-an-nk.nb0.aspx

Comment: Ah, you are right - it works for me now.  The Internet had a hiccup. :)